# MXUnit add return value when using throws()

Tags: unit-testing, coldfusion, coldfusion-10, mxunit

I'm trying to write an MXUnit test for a component I'm mocking up that throws an error. When it throws an error of a certain type I get a struct back from the service I'm calling. Is there a way to mock up a struct and return that with the mock?

The relevant code is

```
bankValidator.getBankName("test",12345).throws("myException");
```

I want a way for that code to `.returns(e)` when  `e = { error = 'Invalid Routing Number'}`. Chaining `.returns()` on the end of my code does not return anything.

Maybe there's a better way to go about achieving this result?